# MATLAB proxy could not be created in 180000 milliseconds

Tags: java, matlab, ubuntu

I am using the matlabcontrol-4.0.0.jar library to call Matlab from Java. This on Ubuntu 11.10, Matlab r2011b and Java version "1.6.0_23".

When trying to run this simple program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MatlabConnectionException,
      MatlabInvocationException {

   //Create a proxy, which we will use to control MATLAB
   MatlabProxyFactory factory = new MatlabProxyFactory(options);
   MatlabProxy proxy = factory.getProxy();

   //Display 'hello world' just like when using the demo
   proxy.eval("disp('hello world')");

   //Disconnect the proxy from MATLAB
   proxy.disconnect();
}
```

I get, after the Matlab launch screen appears (which is good), a time out:

> Exception in thread "main" matlabcontrol.MatlabConnectionException:
>   **MATLAB proxy could not be created in 180000 milliseconds**  at matlabcontrol.RemoteMatlabProxyFactory.getProxy(RemoteMatlabProxyFactory.java:158)
>     at
>   matlabcontrol.MatlabProxyFactory.getProxy(MatlabProxyFactory.java:81)
>     at Main.main(Main.java:15)

I've looked everywhere including all the tips from provided by stackoverflow, but nothing seems to fit the problem i am encountering

*UPDATE*

I forbore to mention that I already tried the scenario described by Joshua Kaplan (thanks!) .This seems be **for my case** of no help, meaning that it just keeps waiting. Could someone perhaps elaborate on the communication protocol between java and the matlab proxy?
 -> It could be an incompatibility issue as well, I've posted on the website delivering the resource, have received no answer so far...

*END UPDATE*

So, any of you a tip where to start looking, that would be wonderful
thanks

Comment: I know this is really old post, but did you ever manage to solve the issue?

Comment: To be honest, I don't remember what I did. I think it had to do with Java, but sorry, too long ago

Comment: I managed to solve it in my usage scenario. The issue was with the user that was trying to execute matlab. It was a (Linux) user without a login shell defined. It turns out (at least) the first time you run matlab, it creates a .matlab directory and writes stuff in it.  Once created I removed the shell again, and everything worked. Should this be an answer rather than a comment?

Answer (score 3):

The `getProxy()` method is a blocking operation with a default timeout of 3 minutes (or 180 seconds or 180000 milliseconds). For most people's machines that is long enough, if the connection was not established in that amount of time then something has gone wrong. However, this timeout can be changed by creating an instance of a `MatlabProxyFactoryOptions` which is done by using a [`MatlabProxyFactoryOptions.Builder`](http://matlabcontrol.googlecode.com/svn/javadocs/doc/matlabcontrol/MatlabProxyFactoryOptions.Builder.html). The `MatlabProxyFactoryOptions` instance you create is passed into [`MatlabProxyFactory`'s constructor](http://matlabcontrol.googlecode.com/svn/javadocs/doc/matlabcontrol/MatlabProxyFactory.html#MatlabProxyFactory%28matlabcontrol.MatlabProxyFactoryOptions%29). Here's an example with a 5 minute timeout:

```
MatlabProxyFactoryOptions options = new MatlabProxyFactoryOptions.Builder()
                                     .setProxyTimeout(300000L)
                                     .build();
MatlabProxyFactory factory = new MatlabProxyFactory(options);
MatlabProxy proxy = factory.getProxy();
```

Alternatively you can request a proxy which is a non-blocking operation that has no timeout. Once the proxy has been created it will be passed to the provided callback. Example:

```
MatlabProxyFactory factory = new MatlabProxyFactory();
factory.requestProxy(new MatlabProxyFactory.RequestCallback()
{
    public void proxyCreated(MatlabProxy proxy)
    {
        //TODO: Make use of the proxy
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! This is a scenario I've already tested and forbore to mention this in my post. I'am truly sorry about that. I think there must be something else blocking. As I have no idea how Java communicates with this proxy (the protocol), I have no idea where to look to.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar problem. Main issue is that in your imported .jar file "matlabcontrol-4.0.0.jar" there is default, configuration in class `Configuration.java`. In my case there was problem, that libraries cannot properly call matlab with all arguments. Try to add to your project not .jar file, but package `matalbcontrol` with all source .java files. You can download it form the same page http://code.google.com/p/matlabcontrol/downloads/list, form where you got .jar libs. Then in `Configuration.java` edit `getMatlabLocation()` lines:

```
else if(isWindows() || isLinux())
{
       matlabLoc = "matlab";
}
```

replace with:

```
    else if(isLinux())
    {
        matlabLoc = "/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/bin/matlab"; //or place where you got installed your matlab, directory bin, in my case, like in example
    }
    else if(isWindows())
    {
        matlabLoc = "matlab";
    }
```

Comment: There is no need to modify this method. The location of MATLAB can be set at runtime by calling the MatlabProxyFactoryOptions.Builder.setMatlabLocation(...) method and passing in the location of MATLAB on your system. In your case you would call this method and provide "/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/bin/matlab".